# Is there a term for the opposite of intergenic?

Tags: dna, terminology, gene

I am looking for a term that describes DNA regions that overlap genes, i.e., non-intergenic DNA regions.
For example, say I am writing a paper about DNA-binding sites (i.e., DNA sequences that proteins bind to), but my paper focuses exclusively on DNA-binding sites that happen to overlap genes. What would my title be? "Non-intergenic DNA-binding sites are [...]" is one option, but I wonder whether a more appropriate term exists.

If I understand correctly, "Gene-overlapping" seems to be used for referring to genes that overlap other genes (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlapping_gene).
Also, Google says that "genic" means "relating to genes".

Is any of my ideas appropriate? Or maybe another term?

---

To clarify what I mean by intergenic and non-intergenic, here is the figure from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intergenic_region. I added an example for a non-intergenic DNA region.
[image]
Explicitly, an intergenic DNA region is a DNA region that doesn't share any base with any gene. A non-intergenic DNA region is a DNA region that shares at least one base with a gene.

Comment: What do you mean by "regions that overlap genes" and how is that different from genes themselves?

Comment: inter means between, intra means within, think inter-state highway.

Comment: @BagiM and John, I tried to clarify. Please point out if it still isn't clear.

Comment: Your "non-intergenic DNA region" overlaps the purple gene and possibly some of the red, too, so I don't understand what's non-intergenic about it.

Comment: @MattDMo If I understand correctly, "intergenic" means between genes, i.e., doesn't overlap genes. Thus, "non-intergenic" means not between genes, i.e., does overlap genes. If this is not accurate, please let me know

Comment: @MattDMo I apologize. I made a horrible mistake in the definition I gave at the end. I fixed it now.

Comment: I wouldn't use non-intergenic to refer to sequences that contain at least one base of a gene, because, at least according to your graphic, a large portion of it still could be intergenic material. Maybe just call them gene-overlapping regions? I'm really not sure.

Comment: @BagiM There are sequences/regions in a genome that are not genes, e.g.: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA_binding_site, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enhancer_(genetics)

Comment: I understand the terms genic and intergenic to be dichotomous, so non-intergenic to me just means genic and I doubt you will find a term of art applicable to your scenario. Some kind of descriptive phrase may be more useful: *”DNA binding sites at the boundaries between genic and intergenic regions are…*” or perhaps *”DNA binding sites at intergenic boundaries are…”*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that "genic" is a perfectly good word.

[This paper](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0003670) uses "genic" directly as a contrast to "intergenic", so that seems like a reasonable precedent:

> ‘Noncoding DNA’ can be found both surrounding genes, and within genes (see schematic Figure 1). We will call the first type ‘intergenic’, and the second type ‘genic’, a ‘gene’ referring here to a transcribed DNA sequence.